# how to query for contact of a customer portal user or community user

Tags: user, customer-community, landing-page

I want to fetch the Contact Id of the Community Portal User. I pass the logged in Member user Id as `uId` to the custom VF page from the Login page and its rendering fine. But when i try to query for user's contact directly i get an error. Can anyone help?

```
userId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('uId');
User u = [SELECT u.Id,u.Contact,u.IsActive from User u where u.Id =: userId AND u.IsActive =: true];
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The error Msg 
"Error: Compile Error: No such column 'Contact' on entity 'User'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

Answer (score 6):

There is no `User.Contact` field, instead you have to user `User.ContactId`

```
userId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('uId');
User u = [SELECT u.Id,u.ContactId,u.IsActive 
          FROM User u 
          WHERE u.Id =: userId 
            AND u.IsActive =: true];
```